# Cumsum with pandas on financial data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm very new to python and I have managed to import data from an excel datasheet using the `pd.read_excel` function. The data is arranged in the following manner in a dataframe :

[image]

I'm trying to do a cumsum() over this dataframe, however I get this error message :

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Timestamp' and 'Timestamp'
```

How can I force only the cumsum() on the returns columns without removing my dates columns ?

I added the data with the following function :
`oFX = pd.read_excel('C:\\Work\\Python Dev\\Athenes\\FX.xlsx', 0)`

The `data.info()` is the following :
`oFX.info()  <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> 
Int64Index: 4133 entries, 0 to 4132 
Data columns (total 11 columns): 
Dates    4133 non-null datetime64[ns] 
AUD      4133 non-null float64 
CAD      4133 non-null float64 
CHF      4133 non-null float64 
EUR      4133 non-null float64 
GBP      4133 non-null float64 
JPY      4133 non-null float64 
KRW      4133 non-null float64 
MEP      4133 non-null float64 
NZD      4133 non-null float64 
USD      4133 non-null float64 
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(10) 
memory usage: 387.5 KB`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post the output from `df.info()`

Comment: `oFX.info()  
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>  
Int64Index: 4133 entries, 0 to 4132  
Data columns (total 11 columns):  
Dates    4133 non-null datetime64[ns]  
AUD      4133 non-null float64  
CAD      4133 non-null float64  
CHF      4133 non-null float64  
EUR      4133 non-null float64  
GBP      4133 non-null float64  
JPY      4133 non-null float64  
KRW      4133 non-null float64  
MEP      4133 non-null float64  
NZD      4133 non-null float64  
USD      4133 non-null float64  
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(10)  
memory usage: 387.5 KB`

Comment: Into your question not as a comment, also post raw input data and how to create your df

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing as your 'Dates' are just daily entries you can temporarily set the index to that column, call `cumsum` and then `reset_index`:

```
oFX.set_index('Dates').cumsum().reset_index()
```

Comment: Thanks! Why reset the index though?

Comment: To get the date column back as regular column